# network configuration in ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, networking, internet, dns

my windows 7 settings is below and its working properly.
IP address 192.168.46.31
Subnet mask 255.255.255.0
Default gateway 192.168.46.1
Preferred DNS server 10.230.253.253
Alternet DNS server 203.147.88.2

but in ubuntu 12.10 i change only to file to make this.
1 is in `/etc/network/interfaces` like below

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
#auto lo
#iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.46.31
netmask 255.255.255.0
#network 192.168.46.0
#broadcast 192.168.46.255
gateway 192.168.46.1
```

and another file is /etc/resolv.conf like

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 10.230.253.253
nameserver 203.147.88.2
```

but its not connecting. when i click to the "connection information" its showing "no valid connection information found"

and when im pinging to DNS its showing like that

```
$ ping 10.230.253.253
PING 10.230.253.253 (10.230.253.253) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.46.31 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
```

am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment the following lines

`auto lo`

`iface lo inet loopback`

`network 192.168.46.0`

And then disable and enable networking.

You might also try setting up the manual configuration through the graphical network manager.

Comment: after that i need to give username and password in "24online client" software but in ubuntu where can i give the username and password? it may b silly qu, :P but i am new linux user.
i have done this through GUI.but somehow its not working.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean about logging in. Are you able to connect to a network? Please edit you question to clarify.

Comment: just configuration is not enough. in windows7 i have a software named "24online client" through it i need to login to the server just like broadband. then i'll be connected to internet.

Comment: Do you log in through a web browser? I have seen some of these network login deals that wont redirect automatically except in IE.